# Reading syslog-ng logs from the unix socket diretly

Tags: sockets, nginx, netcat

I have nginx configured to use syslog and  unix sockets:

```
access_log syslog:server=unix:/var/run/syslog-ng.sock,tag=ngw_access,facility=local7,severity=info;
```

The syslog service then sends the logs to a remote location.
I would like to read the logs from the socket file directly rather than changing the configuration of nginx to put logs into a text file each time I have to debug the message.

I tried using NC (netcat) both traditional and BSD versions:

```
$ nc -luD /var/run/syslog-ng.sock
nc: getaddrinfo: Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

Let me know if this is possible to do.

P.S.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config nc
There are 2 choices for the alternative nc (providing /bin/nc).
Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nc.openbsd       50        auto mode
  1            /bin/nc.openbsd       50        manual mode
  2            /bin/nc.traditional   10        manual mode
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried configuring syslog-ng to read messages from the socket? I mean, using a unix-stream source like this: https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-sources-unixstream.html

and including the source in a log statement?

Comment: Thanks for that, but no, I have not. It would be amazing for me to just read whatever the socket is receiving. This would be best for my use-case I think as I don't have free-reign access to some of the servers.